# Error on Auto completion

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

```
 <td id="Nico{!(ROUND(rowNum,0))}">
                                                <apex:inputField value="{!qli.Name}" id="Name" style="width:110px"  required="true" StyleClass="AutoPin" onmouseover="javascript: nicopinClient  = '{!(ROUND(rowNum,0))}'; " />      
                                            </td>      
                                            <td id="client{!(ROUND(rowNum,0))}">
                                                <apex:inputField value="{!qli.Client_P_N__c}" style="width:110px;"/> 
                                            </td>
```

I am changing the above code to

```
<apex:column headerValue="Name" id="nico{!(ROUND(wrapper.ident,0))}"><apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Name}" StyleClass="AutoPin" onmouseover="javascript: nicopinClient = '{!(ROUND(wrapper.ident,0))}';" id="Name"/></apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Client P/N" id="client{!(ROUND(wrapper.ident,0))}"><apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Client_P_N__c}" style="width:110px;"  /> </apex:column>
```

it is Throwing error like this :

> Literal value is required for attribute id in `<apex:column>`

How can i overcome from this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign Dynamic id to apex tag. that cause this problem. You can use `Styleclass` for any reference or condition or need to use html tag.